# Cant see Object with "ocean" modifier through glass

Tags: transparency, eevee-render-engine, glass

I have a small issue with transmission. I cant see objects with "ocean" modifier through and object with transmission.

In the example you will see that the transmission is working on the blue object, but not on the one with the *Ocean Modifier*.

I am using EEVEE in Blender 2.82.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunatelly Eevee is very bad at glass. This is one of the render engine's limitations.

Comment: I have noticed other problems with lighting too, however, there should be a trick or solution in Eevee for that issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting very constructive and utterly important changes in my question structure, I have found out, that the "transmission" DOES in fact work on the Ocean Modifier. After creating the scene in a new file, I haven't changed any setting, only the material of the objects. I think there was a mistake in the light setting or a change in the World Properties, that made the transmission not working probably.

[image]